# WordPress, oEmbed & YouTube video's with a 'dash'

Tags: youtube, oembed

I am having an issue where a video with a 'dash' (-) in the url are not being embedded in WordPress.  This is happening when pasting the URL into a page / post and is also able to be reproduced when using the `wp_oembed_get` command.

The YouTube URL in question is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uf-M3PTXuIs

Any YouTube URL which does not have a 'dash' (-) embeds without issue.

I have not found much information on this issue, but a post I did stumble upon suggested deleting the video from YouTube and adding it again to get a new URL (https://wordpress.org/support/topic/youtube-embed-fails-when-video-url-has-dash-in-it?replies=9), however, I am not the owner of the video so this is not an option.

Any suggestions on how to fix / work around this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the YouTube video in question had Embedding disabled by request.  Tested with other YouTube videos with a 'dash' and they work fine (if embedding is not disabled).

Comment: How did you find out?